# The correct way to use new DocumentClient()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I see the following error occasionally in my ec2 instance that uses DynamoDB  heavily

```
{ message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
code: 'CredentialsError',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '169.254.169.254',
port: 80,
time: 2018-07-05T10:02:37.690Z,
originalError: 
{ code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '169.254.169.254',
port: 80,
message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80' } } }
```

The way I am using the AWS sdk to connect and get data from DynamoDB is like the following

```
'use strict'
const BluebirdPromise = require('bluebird')
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(BluebirdPromise)
const DocumentClient = AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient

class DynamoOne {

  get({
    key
  }) {
    return new DocumentClient().get({ // creating new instance every time i want to get Item
        Key: key,
        TableName: 'TABLE_NAME',
        ConsistentRead: consistent,
      })
      .promise()
      .catch(e => console.trace(key, e))
  }
}

new DynamoOne.get({
  id: 1
}).then((item) => {
  console.log(1, item)
})
```

Is this the correct way to use it ? or I should create `new DocumentClient()` once and use it all over , like the following code

```
'use strict'
const BluebirdPromise = require('bluebird')
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(BluebirdPromise)
const DocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() // creating new instance once

class DynamoTwo {

  get({
    key
  }) {
    return DocumentClient.get({ // reuse DocumentClient
        Key: key,
        TableName: 'TABLE_NAME',
        ConsistentRead: consistent,
      })
      .promise()
      .catch(e => console.trace(key, e))
  }

}


new DynamoTwo.get({
  id: 1
}).then((item) => {
  console.log(1, item)
})
```

Which one is the correct one DynamoOne or DynamoTwo ?

Comment: The error is not document client error. Its AWS.Config error. It cannot load credentials for dynamodb. How do you specify credentials? Environment Variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and [asking in github aws repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2131) 
I found that the correct way is to use `DynamoTwo`